# Flutter - keep listen a stream on page change

Tags: flutter, navigation, system.reactive

My scenario is like this:

- a BottomNavigationBar where one page contains a list of items ("listPage") and another page is a single item ("itemPage").
- both pages can navigate to "itemPage" related to a different items.
- the "itemPage" show details of the product and have a "Favourite" toggle button.
- in the "listPage" every item shown via ListView.builder, show and can handle the "Favourite" toggle button.

I can't understand how reflect the "Favourite" change in an "itemPage" to others "itemPage" (if opened multiple time for the same item, yes, it's possible) and also to the same item in the "pageList".

I created a NotifierBloc where a BehaviorSubject > Sink is called every time a "Favourite" toggle button change its state (putting the itemId and the boolean value of the Favourite). After a database update an output PublishSubject > Stream is filled with the additional information of the item.
In this way every time a "Favourite" is toggled, all the subscribers receive the info about the flag.

```
  BehaviorSubject<Item> inController = new BehaviorSubject<Item>();
  Sink<Item> get putUpdate => inController.sink;

  final PublishSubject<Item> outController = PublishSubject<Item>();
  Stream<Item> get getUpdates => outController.stream;

  NotifierBloc() {
    inController.listen(_handleToggle);
  }

  _handleToggle(Item item) {
    ...
    outController.sink.add(newItemAfterDatabaseCall);
  }
```

In ListPage and ItemPage (both StatefulWidget) I created a StreamSubscription in DidChangeDependencies method which listen to the NotifierBloc Stream.
The StreamSubscription will be cancelled in the Dispose method.

```
  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _subscription = _notifierBloc.getUpdates.listen((item) => {
          // Do things with the Item like setState or call bloc methods
          ...
        });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Problems are when a new itemPage is opened: the dispose method cancel the subscription in the previous shown page, so new events will not be get listened.

In addition when a page is shown due to a previous page close, the StreamSubscription is renewed and I get updates about the last one Favourite change, but I need a list of Favourite changes, because maybe the user opened several "itemPage"s.

How can I solve?

Maybe the Stream must be passed to the Page(not the PageState)? But how to handle onData function?

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of state management system. Look into `Provider`. Here is a simple example of how you could use it. https://github.com/m-Skolnick/provider_example_flutter